# Nodejs and update file inside zip archive

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems, zip, php-ziparchive

I want update file in zip arhive with `nodejs`. For example i have zip file with two files:

```
 a.zip
   |-a.txt
   |-b.txt
```

I use archiver:

```
var archiver = require('archiver');
var archive = archiver('zip', {});
archive.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./a.zip'));
archive.append(fs.createReadStream('./c.txt'), { name: 't.txt' });
archive.finalize();
```

But I have a problem, my archive is completely overwritten. As a result, I get:

```
 a.zip
   |-t.txt
```

If I use:

```
archive.file('./a.txt', { name: 't.txt' });
```

the result remains the same.
And I want to get this structure as a result

```
 a.zip
   |-a.txt
   |-b.txt
   |-t.txt
```

Or update the contents of one of the files `a.txt` or `b.txt`

Answer (score 3):

Appending to an existing archive is currently not possible with `archiver`. Here's the relevant issue opened in 2013: [support appending to existing archives #23](https://github.com/archiverjs/node-archiver/issues/23)

In your case, `append` is appending to the *stream*, not to whatever was at the destination of the new file. `archiver` doesn't care about what's at `a.zip`, it just overwrites it with whatever you give to `archiver.append`.

It seems like your best bet would be to unzip the existing file with [maxogden/**extract-zip**](https://github.com/maxogden/extract-zip), then append the results to the new version of the archive with `archiver`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **JSZip**. You can refer to the official [documentation](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/).

And here's a simple Node.js example:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var JSZip = require("jszip");

async function zipDemo() {
    // read the existing zip file
    var zipData = fs.readFileSync("input.zip");
    var zip = await JSZip.loadAsync(zipData);
    // add a new JSON file to the zip
    zip.file("sample.json", JSON.stringify({demo:123}));
    // write out the updated zip
    zip.generateNodeStream({type:'nodebuffer', streamFiles:true})
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('output.zip'))
    .on('finish', function () {
        console.log("output`enter code here`.zip written.");
    });
}

zipDemo();
```